# How to split a formatted string?

Tags: c#, .net, string

```
string text = "try your {{equal|even out|regularize}  out|steady|tied|equal}";
```

Actually I want to split all words within the outer brackets (`{}`).

For example, if this is the string: `"{{equal|even out|regularize}  out|steady|tied|equal}"`, I want the split result array to be this:
    { equal,
    even out,
    regularize,
    out,
    steady,
    tied,
    equal }

```
string text = "try your {{equal|even out|regularize}  out|steady|tied|equal}  {champion|finest|top-quality}";

string1 = "try";
string2 = "your";
string3="{{equal|even out|regularize}  out|steady|tied|equal}";
string4="{champion|finest|top-quality}";
```

How to split like this... please help me... Thanks !

Comment: You should present what you have tried and why that did not work

Comment: Make a substring for the first brackets then split based on { } and |, remove empty entries and trim

Comment: not sure how this is linked to WPF...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
string text = "try your {{equal|even out|regularize}  out|steady|tied|equal}";
text = text.Remove(0, text.IndexOf('{'));
var array = text.Split('{', '}', '|');
array.ToList().ForEach(item =>
{
      Console.WriteLine(item);
});
```

output :

```
equal
even out
regularize
  out
steady
tied
equal
```

Comment: Ashok I have one more doubt.. please help me

Comment: string text = "try your {{equal|even out|regularize}  out|steady|tied|equal}  {champion|finest|top-quality}";

Comment: I want to separate like this String1 = "try"; string2 = "your"; string3 = {{equal|even out|regularize}  out|steady|tied|equal}; string4 ={champion|finest|top-quality};

Comment: u should have asked that in ur question.